MAUI DevExpress DataGridView - Binding to Custom Dynamic DataType
I am attempting to create a datagridview using the devexpress toolkit for MAUI, but just cant seem to get it right. I have a custome datastructure that I have to adhere to and want to bind the columns to fields in my data.
I start off by creating a datagridview object and set up columns inside of it based on the field entries in my data.
Find here a snippet of my custom data:
public class Form
{
    //Attributes
    public List<Row> RowList { get; set; }

    public Form()
    {
        this.RowList = new();
        this.RowList.Add(new Row());
    }
}

public class Row
{
    //Attributes
    public List<Column> ColumnList { get; set; }

    public Row()
    {
        this.ColumnList = new();
        this.ColumnList.Add(new Column() { ColumnName = "Personal Details" });
        this.ColumnList.Add(new Column() { ColumnName = "Products" });
        this.ColumnList.Add(new Column() { ColumnName = "Employees" });
    }
}

public class Column
{
    //Attributes
    public long ColumnId { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public List<Record> RecordList { get; set; }

    public Column()
    {
        this.RecordList = new();
    }
}

public class Record 
{
    //Attributes
    public List<Field> FieldList { get; set; }

    public Record()
    {
        this.FieldList = new();
    }  
}

public class Field
{
    public long FieldId { get; set; }
    public string FieldLabel { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
} 

And here is a snippet of sample data that gets populated into the objects:
this.RowList[0].ColumnList[0].RecordList.Add(new Record()
{
    FieldList = new List<Field>
    {
        new Field { FieldId = 1, FieldLabel = "Name", Value = "Corne" },
        new Field { FieldId = 2, FieldLabel = "Surname", Value = "Ackerman" },
        new Field { FieldId = 3, FieldLabel = "Age", Value = 23 },
        new Field { FieldId = 4, FieldLabel = "Email", Value = "corne@test.com" }
    }
});

The DataGridView can be bound directly to an itemsource, and I have attempted binding it to multiple parts of the object that I instantiated a Form form = new(); and then I put in the sample data.
I instantiate a DataGridView Object and then itterate through the fields to get the fieldnames and add each as a column with the relevant type. When adding the columns, I tried setting the databindings there but nothing that I did seemed to work. The issue is basically that the databinding doesnt know how to go into RecordList[].FieldList[].Value, I cant tell it that "you are record 2 and field 4, so go to recordlist[2].fieldlist[3].value".
My previous workarounds was flattening the data to display it, which works, but I need a two-way databinding, and this is what is stoppign me from doing something mroe simple.
Find below my DataGridView Setup code:
void setupGrids(MainPageViewModel vm)
{
    // Iterate through columns
    foreach (var col in vm.Form.RowList[0].ColumnList)
    {
        // Create new grid with default properties
        DataGridView grid = new()
        {
            ReduceHeightToContent = true,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20),
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(2),
            EditorShowMode = EditorShowMode.DoubleTap,
            AllowDragDropRows = true,
            AutoGenerateColumnsMode = AutoGenerateColumnsMode.Auto,
        };

        //Add label with column name
        Label label = new()
        {
            Text = col.ColumnName,
            FontSize = 20,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 10),
        };
        labels.Add(label);

        // Iterate through records and fields to add relevant column types to grid
        // Goes through all records in case some fields are not present in all records (ex. fields added later)
        // Iterate through fields to add relevant column types to grid
        foreach (var recordList in col.RecordList)
        {
            // Iterate through fields
            foreach (var field in recordList.FieldList)
            {
                // Check if column hasn't been added yet
                if (grid.Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.FieldName == field.FieldLabel) == null)
                {
                    // Calculate width of column based on length of data and ColumnName
                    int width = field.Value.ToString().Length * 13;
                    int titleWidth = field.FieldLabel.ToString().Length * 13;
                    width = width < 100 ? 100 : width;
                    width = titleWidth > width ? titleWidth : width;


                    // Check data type and set column type accordingly
                    if (field.Value.GetType() == typeof(int))
                    {
                        grid.Columns.Add(new NumberColumn()
                        {
                            FieldName = field.FieldLabel,
                            Caption = field.FieldLabel,
                            MinWidth = width,
                        });
                    }
                    else if (field.Value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        grid.Columns.Add(new DateColumn()
                        {
                            FieldName = field.FieldLabel,
                            Caption = field.FieldLabel,
                            MinWidth = width,
                        });
                    }
                    else if (field.Value.GetType() == typeof(bool))
                    {
                        grid.Columns.Add(new CheckBoxColumn()
                        {
                            FieldName = field.FieldLabel,
                            Caption = field.FieldLabel,
                            MinWidth = width,
                        });
                    }
                    else if (field.Value.GetType() == typeof(decimal) || //All number types
                             field.Value.GetType() == typeof(long) ||
                             field.Value.GetType() == typeof(int) ||
                             field.Value.GetType() == typeof(short) |
                             field.Value.GetType() == typeof(float) ||
                             field.Value.GetType() == typeof(double))
                    {
                        grid.Columns.Add(new NumberColumn()
                        {
                            FieldName = field.FieldLabel,
                            Caption = field.FieldLabel,
                            MinWidth = width,
                            BindingContext = col.RecordList[0],
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid.Columns.Add(new TextColumn()
                        {
                            FieldName = field.FieldLabel,
                            Caption = field.FieldLabel,
                            MinWidth = width,
                            BindingContext = col.RecordList[0].FieldList[0],

                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Set Source
        //grid.ItemsSource = vm.getTable(col);
        grid.ItemsSource = col.RecordList;
        vm.GridList.Add(grid);
    } // foreach column 
}

private void addGridsToView(MainPageViewModel vm)
{
    int c = 0;
    // Iterate through gridList and add each grid to the stack layout
    foreach (var grid in vm.GridList)
    {
        int i = 0;
        //Apply additional formatting to headers
        grid.Columns.ForEach(c =>
        {
            c.HeaderFontSize = 17;
            c.HeaderBackgroundColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromRgba(173, 216, 230, 255);
            c.HeaderFontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
            //c.SetBinding(TitleProperty, "FieldList.Field.FieldLabel");
            //c.SetBinding(ContentProperty, new Binding("Value"));
            //c.SetBinding(TitleProperty, new Binding("FieldName"));
            //c.SetBinding(GridColumn.BindingContextProperty, "FieldList.Value.Value");
        });
        stack.Children.Add(labels[c++]);
        stack.Children.Add(grid);
    }

}

I need to keep it all dynamic as possible. the setbinding() method is what I think i need to use, but in conjunction with it the BindingContext. I set the context to the recordlist as that is where all the data is found that needs to be displayed. The databinding needs to be two-way.
Find here my github repo that I am currently using to try and figure out a solution to this problem (this repo does not contain any sensitive info) : https://github.com/corne-ac/DX-test-app
I tried multiple bindingcontexts:
BindingContext = col.RecordList;

(the one  I think is closest to the solution)
BindingContext = new Binding("RecordList");`  
BindingContext = col.RecordList[0].FieldList[0];

(even tried hardcoding indexes)
These below I tried to apply to the columns but none seemed to work:
//c.SetBinding(TitleProperty, "FieldList.Field.FieldLabel");
    
//c.SetBinding(TitleProperty, "FieldList\[\*\].value");
    
//c.SetBinding(ContentProperty, new Binding("Value"));
    
//c.SetBinding(TitleProperty, new Binding("FieldName"));   

//c.SetBinding(GridColumn.BindingContextProperty, "RecordList\[\**\].FieldList\[\**\].Value");


There doesn’t appear to be any match between the values of FieldName  and the property names in your data

@Jason , sorry yeah, Basically the FieldName is the column Title and the value is the data, each recordlist item is a row entry in theory. The rowentry is a list of fields where each field has the column name it belongs to and a value. Inside the Grid.Columns.Add() body, I had a bindingcontext = field, just not present in thesnippet presented, as it didnt work yet.

The grid uses the FieldName property to match to a property in your model.  If there is no match no data will display.  The docs and samples for this are pretty good, have you read them?  You should not have to assign binding context for individual cells
